# Is there any PowerShell command to get the details for all Azure VM's that JIT (Just in Times) is assigned or not?

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, jit

I am working to JIT (Just in time). It should be enabled in all Azure Virtual Machines.
For that, I am retrieving the details to see how many VM's JIT is enabled or disabled.

Is there any script or command to get these details via PowerShell which gives details in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

The command should be [Get-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.security/get-azjitnetworkaccesspolicy?view=azps-8.0.0)

```
# Sample from microsoft docs
Get-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy 

Id                : /subscriptions/487bb485-b5b0-471e-9c0d-10717612f869/resourceGroups/myService1/providers/Microsoft.Security/locations/centralus/jitNetworkAccessPolicies/default
Name              : default
Kind              : Basic
VirtualMachines   : {/subscriptions/487bb485-b5b0-471e-9c0d-10717612f869/resourceGroups/myService1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testService}
Requests          : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Security.Models.JitNetworkAccessPolicies.PSSecurityJitNetworkAccessPolicyRequest}
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
```

It's part of the Az.Security Module.

The command will show you all Just in Time Policies and the assigned machines (VirtualMachines Property)
Together with **Get-AzVM** you can create a list of which don't have JIT enabled yet.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Import-Module Az.Compute
Import-Module Az.Security
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId "<Id>"

$AzJITPolicies = Get-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy 
$AzVMs = Get-AzVM
$ResultSet = @("VmName;JITEnabled")

foreach($AzVM in $AzVMS) {
    # You probably need to filter the rules even further here.
    $PolicyExists = $AzJITPolicies | Where-Object { $_.VirtualMachines | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $AzVm.Id }}
    $JITEnabled = $false
    if($PolicyExists) {
        $JITEnabled = $true
    }

    $ResultSet += ($AzVM.Name + ";" + $JITEnabled)

}

# export as csv => import in excel
$ResultSet -join "`r`n" | Out-File "c:\result.csv"
```

Comment: Huge thanks to you! Exactly what I was searching for today and it works beautifully

Comment: In this case you should accept it as solution ;)